# Json Deserialization and printing non-primitive object using c# and ASP.NET MVC and JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net, deserialization

I have generated a json file from Wen api which contain the Name, Shortext, Geoco-ordinates including latitude and longitude and Images. Now I want to Deserialize every object in the contrller cass so that I can show these in View. My json file look like this.

```
        {
        "poi":[
                {
                  "Name": "Berlin",
                  "Shorttext": "Berlin is the capital of Germany and one of the 16 states of Germany.....",
                  "GeoCoordinates": {
                    "Longitude": 13.38333333,
                    "Latitude": 52.51666667
                  },
                  "Images": [
                    "BA5AB22B.jpg"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "Name": "munich",
                 "Shorttext": "Munich of the European Union with a population of above 1.5 million.....",
                  "GeoCoordinates": {
                    "Longitude": 11.56666667,
                    "Latitude": 48.13333333
                  },
                  "Images": [
                    "AA3CF664.jpg"
                  ]
                }
        ]
    }
```

My Model class for this object is -

```
public class GeoCoordinates
{
  public double Longitude { get; set; }
  public double Latitude { get; set; }
 }

 public class Poi
  {
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Shorttext { get; set; }
   public GeoCoordinates GeoCoordinates { get; set; }
   public List<string> Images { get; set; }
  }

  public class RootObject
  {
    public List<Poi> poi { get; set; }
  }
```

I want to get every object from this class such as shorttext, latitude, longitude, images. How can I Deserialize using Json.net to get every single object.

I want my result in that way-

```
Name:
Shortext:
Latititude
Longitude:
Images:
```

Edited: Iam trying to get value in this way-

```
       var ReadJson = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"E:\C# Learning\POI.json");
        RootObject json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(ReadJson);

        foreach (var item in json.poi)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("name: {0}, shorttext : {1}, Geo: {2} ,Image:{3}", item.Name, item.Shorttext,item.GeoCoordinates,item.Images);
        }
```

Comment: Well, you've got the class, and you've got the JSON... what happens if you just use `JsonConver.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json)`?

Comment: The edit doesn't explain anything. You asked about deserialization, not rendering. What is the actual question?

Comment: `JsonConver` is a typo. use `JsonConvert` instead.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh, `sonConvert` is a typo, use `JsonConvert` instead :)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos at first I want to deserialize every object and then want my result in that way I mentioned in edited question.

Comment: And? Did you encounter a problem? Have you tried something? Why shouldn't this question be closed as a duplicate of many others? BTW if you have *two* question, make two separate posts. Both questions separately have a lot of answers already

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I have edited my question and gave my further work. But in this way it is not working

Comment: What isn't working? In any case, instead of using the archaic JavaScriptSerializer use the defacto standard [Json.NET]9http://json.net/) library, as mentioned by the very first commenter. And *please* search for similar questions - I've answered an identical one 15 minutes ago

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ok I am explaining to you. I already got Json class. And now I want to deserialize it. As I am very new handling this situation I want to know what is the correct way to get every single object from this json. So that it can read every places information. I am searching but could not find any suitable solution for this.I am really Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: Why not that : List<Poi> mycities = json.poi;. You want a List<Poi> and you have it in your RootObject ?

Comment: @Thomas , I am not getting any correct way how to get every single value as I mentioned in the desired result.

Comment: @Thomas: After modifying my question I have got result for name, Shorttext correctly but for geocoordinates and images it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) you can do something like this(it should also work with the `JavaScriptSerializer`) :

```
var ReadJson = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"E:\C# Learning\POI.json");
RootObject json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(ReadJson);
foreach (var item in json.poi)
{
    Console.WriteLine("name: {0}, shorttext : {1}, Latitutde: {2} , Latitutde: {3}, Image: {4}", item.Name, item.Shorttext, item.GeoCoordinates.Latitude, item.GeoCoordinates.Longitude, string.Join(" ", item.Images));
}
```

Anyway you should explain what is the problem... what are the expected output and the output you have for the moment...

Look at these articles:

- [Why and How to Override ToString() Method in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a42a0c/why-how-to-override-tostring-method-in-C-Sharp/)
- [C# Convert List to String](http://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-list-string)

Comment: Can you update the title of your question because this is not about Parsing Json. This is more about printing non-primitive object.

Comment: Yes I have modified my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try Deserialize in

```
List<Dictionary<string,string>>()
```

and then you can extract data as:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(ReadJson);
// you can simply pass your JSON string in place of ReadJson if you don't want to create a file
var val1  = data.Select(y => y["property name"]).Single();
var val2  = data.Select(y => y["property name"]).Single();
// and so on
```